# how can i validate(phone number validation) each array item in script using flex

Tags: apache-flex

```
var str:String=cntslst.text;      
var results:Array = str.split(",");
for(i=0;i<result.length;i++)
{<mx:NumberValidator source="{result[i]}" property="text" id="cell" />}
```

is it possible ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the PhoneNumberValidator class, instantiated in either AS3 or MXML is fine. Don't set the source or property properties unless you want validation error UI to appear.

You can then call the validate method on that instance for each string and check to see if the results property of the ValidationResultEvent that is returned is null or empty.

```
var validator:PhoneNumberValidator; //instantiate how you like
var result:ValidationResultEvent = validator.validate(str);
var isPhoneNumber:Boolean = result.results == null || result.results.length == 0;
```

Comment: You should mark it as the answer so others know in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about not setting the source or property props.  +1